# Why might Eclipse fail to show "Ant Build" in the run options for an Ant build file?

Tags: eclipse, ant

Usually, when I right-click an Ant buildfile in the Eclipse Package Explorer and select "Run As" from the context menu, I get the options "Ant Build" and "Ant Build..." to choose from. This is the correct behavior.

Once in a while, those options get replaced by options that have nothing to do with Ant, like "JUnit test" and "Java applet." What can cause Eclipse to lose its context-sensitivity and not show the correct options there? How can I fix it?

I've seen this in multiple versions of Eclipse, on both Windows XP and Windows 7. It doesn't seem to matter whether the file is named `build.xml` or not. Regardless of whether this error occurs, the build files are shown with the Ant icon in the Package Explorer, not the generic XML file icon. And even when the weird behavior happens, alternate methods of running the build do work, like going through the Run menu or opening the file and right-clicking the editor.

The only "solution" I've been able to find so far is to keep restarting Eclipse until it starts working again, which is just kicking the can down the road, not actually solving anything.

EDIT:
I'm now experiencing occasional instances of context menus for Maven POMs displaying Ant build options under "Run As." Maybe "incorrect 'Run As' options" is a wider Eclipse issue?

Comment: Interesting question but it certainly doesn't belong here. Sure looks like a bug - feel free to open a bug report at eclipse.org.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure if this was an Eclipse bug or if I had a wonky configuration. But this is a year and a half old now, and I don't even have the system that I was experiencing the issue on anymore, so... I'll leave it to someone else to report. If it hasn't already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In context of an eclipse plugin developer all such pop up menus, menus and toolbar actions are called commands/action-sets. These elements have their visible-when and enable-when checks to display them at required conditions. The conditions include the required active pespective, active view, requiring selection and validity of the selection. Most of the case the options not displayed are due to failure of the condition which are actually expected behavior. All such conditions should have been documented by mentioning these conditions directly or indirectly in their documentation. In case any of the conditions not implemented properly, we can always raise bug to the eclipse community in [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). Before raising a bug the similar existing bugs should be checked if there is one already.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could add the ant scripts to the Ant View. The scripts are easier to find from there than from the package explorer, and you can easily even execute other targets than the default.